# Web part edit button not appearing?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm using MOSS 2007 with Publishing Site and have added an Image Web Part to a page using Sharepoint Designer.

When I go into the browser to edit the page, the edit button on the web part does not appear.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To edit a webpart in a browser it needs to be inserted inside a Web Part Zone, try adding one in your page then adding the webpart to it. If still no luck or if you already have a Web Part zone, go on its properties (right click => Web Part Zone Properties) and see if users are allowed to edit it in browser.